# Entity Framework com Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-6, migrations

Estou tentando usar o EF, usando Code Frist, junto com um banco de dados Oracle, para isso estou utilizando o pacote do Nuget [Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework/), porém sempre que eu tento executar o `Update-Database` ele dá a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type is not
>   resolved for member
>   'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException,Oracle.ManagedDataAccess,
>   Version=4.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342'.
>
> at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate
>   callBackDelegate)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner
>   runner)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String
>   targetMigration, Boolean force)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action
>   command)
>       Type is not resolved for member 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException,Oracle.ManagedDataAccess,
>   Version=4.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342'.

Meu contexto, minha classe e web.config estão da seguinte maneira:

```
public class MeuContext : DbContext
{
    public MeuContext()
        : base("OracleDbContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<GrupoProduto> GrupoProdutos { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder dbModelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(dbModelBuilder);
        dbModelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("atlas");
        dbModelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

Classe:

```
public class GrupoProduto
{
    [Key]
    public Guid GrupoProdutoId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    [DisplayName("Nome")]
    public String Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Web.Config:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="OracleDbContext" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="User Id=atlas;Password=atlas;Data Source=oracle" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <dataSources>
        <dataSource alias="oracle" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XE))) " />
      </dataSources>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Infelizmente eu, mesmo gostando muito do banco de dados Oracle, desaconselho usar `EF Migrations` com Oracle. Eles não dão atenção apropriada para seu *provider* e sempre tem vários problemas como esse seu. Trabalhei com EF + Oracle por quase 2 anos, e nunca fui 100% feliz. E pelo visto ainda não mudou muito esse cenário.

Recomendo mudar sua estratégia de *Database Update* para *Change Scripts* ao invés de *Migrations*.

Se estiver trabalhando com uma aplicação que será hospedada em VM, vc pode instalar a dll da Oracle no GAC. Mas se for hospedar em PaaS - onde não terá acesso ao host, apenas poderá publicar aplicações - já não é uma opção.

```
C:\Windows\system32>cd E:\smn\packages\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.12.1.021\lib\net40

C:\Windows\system32>e:

E:\smn\packages\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.12.1.021\lib\net40>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\gacutil.exe" /i Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll
Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.33440
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Assembly successfully added to the cache
```

[Snippet copiado dessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32924359/2520523).

Comment: Só um comentário, essa DLL pode ser achava dentro da pasta do nuget qnd se instala a biblioteca do ODP.Net. Além disso percebi q ele não funciona com `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled` habilitado, ou eu estou afzendo algo de errado?

Comment: Não, como eu disse, a Oracle não dá devida atenção para seu provider. Vc Flfaz certinho. Talvez seja um bug. Tente reportar na Oracle, acho que irão ajudar mais rapidamente.